# What is the correct way to fetch a List of Entities from the SQlite Database using Room in Android?

Tags: android, android-room

This is the content of AlarmResourceDao.kt file:

```
@Dao
interface AlarmResourceDao {

    @Query(
        value = """
            SELECT * FROM alarm_resources
            WHERE
                is_scheduled = 'T'
            ORDER BY id ASC
        """
    )
    fun getAllScheduledAlarmResources(): Flow<List<AlarmResourceEntity>>

    @Query(
        value = """
            SELECT *  FROM alarm_resources
            WHERE id = :id
        """
    )
    fun getAlarmResource(id: Int): Flow<AlarmResourceEntity>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertOrIgnoreAlarmResource(entity: AlarmResourceEntity): Long
}
```

I am using the following BooleanConverter to convert the boolean values to string and vice versa:

```
class BooleanConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun charToBoolean(value: Char): Boolean {
        return when(value?: 'F') {
            'T' -> true
            't' -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun booleanToChar(boolean: Boolean): Char {
        return when(boolean) {
            true -> 'T'
            false -> 'F'
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to test the database operations but the following test case always fails:

```
class AlarmResourceDaoTest {
    private val TAG: String = "Morning Walk Alarm"
    private lateinit var alarmResourceDao: AlarmResourceDao
    private lateinit var db: ScDatabase

    @Before
    fun createDb() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            context,
            ScDatabase::class.java,
        ).build()
        alarmResourceDao = db.alarmResourceDao()
    }

    @Test
    fun alarmResourceDao_fetches_scheduled_alarms_by_ascending_id() = runTest {
        val alarmResourceEntities = listOf(
            testAlarmResource(
                id = 0,
                label = "Morning Walk",
                scheduledTime = LocalTime.of(5, 0, 0),
                isScheduled = true,
            ),
            testAlarmResource(
                id = 1,
                label = "Lunch",
                scheduledTime = LocalTime.of(12, 0, 0),
                isScheduled = false,
            ),
            testAlarmResource(
                id = 2,
                label = "Dinner",
                scheduledTime = LocalTime.of(8, 0, 0),
                isScheduled = true,
            ),
            testAlarmResource(
                id = 3,
                label = "Android Development",
                scheduledTime = LocalTime.of(9, 0, 0),
                isScheduled = false,
            )
        )
        for( alarmResourceEntity in alarmResourceEntities) {
            alarmResourceDao.insertOrIgnoreAlarmResource(
                alarmResourceEntity
            )
        }

        val morningWalkAlarm = alarmResourceDao.getAlarmResource(0).first()
        Log.i(TAG, "Morning Walk Alarm 1: ${morningWalkAlarm.toString()}")

        val scheduledAlarmResourceEntities = alarmResourceDao.getAllScheduledAlarmResources()
            .first()

        Log.i(TAG, "Morning Walk Alarm 2: ${scheduledAlarmResourceEntities[0].toString()}")

        assertEquals(
            "Morning Walk",
            scheduledAlarmResourceEntities[0].label
        )
    }
}
```

Inside the test, I have logged twice with the `Morning Walk Alarm` tag but it is only logged once which is before fetching all the Scheduled Alarm Entities.

These are the logs when the test is run:

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (17813) for package com.example.clock.core.database ----------------------------
2023-10-24 11:46:19.173 17813-17837 Morning Walk Alarm      com.example.clock.core.database  I  Morning Walk Alarm 1: AlarmResourceEntity(id=0, label=Morning Walk, scheduledTime=05:00, isScheduled=true)
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (17813) for package com.example.clock.core.database ----------------------------
```

This is the Test result:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
at java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:434)
at com.example.clock.core.database.AlarmResourceDaoTest$alarmResourceDao_fetches_scheduled_alarms_by_ascending_id$1.invokeSuspend(AlarmResourceDaoTest.kt:75)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestDispatcher.processEvent$kotlinx_coroutines_test(TestDispatcher.kt:28)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineScheduler.tryRunNextTaskUnless$kotlinx_coroutines_test(TestCoroutineScheduler.kt:103)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$workRunner$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:320)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:13)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:308)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:166)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(TestBuilders.kt:158)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(Unknown Source:1)
at com.example.clock.core.database.AlarmResourceDaoTest.alarmResourceDao_fetches_scheduled_alarms_by_ascending_id(AlarmResourceDaoTest.kt:36)
```

From the test, I can conclude that the `insertion` and `querying` of `AlarmResourceEntity` by `id` works fine but when multiple `AlarmResourceEntities` are fetched from the database then problem arises.

Could you please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Did you register your TypeConverter class using the `TypeConverters` annotation in the database class?

Comment: @BenjyTec Yes, I have registered the Converter.

Comment: To further track down the issue, remove the `WHERE is_scheduled = 'T'` clause and then see whether the query then returns all stored `AlarmResourceEntities`. If yes, then there is something wrong with the Converter.

Comment: @BenjyTec this time I removed the `WHERE is_scheduled = 'T'` from the query and the test successfully passed. I believe, as you are saying, there must be something wrong with the Converter.

Comment: I see. Next, please add a logging statement or a breakpoint to your `booleanToChar` function and see whether the function is actually executed when inserting data. It might be that Room ignores the TypeConverter because boolean is a supported type.

Comment: I added the logs in both `charToBoolean(value: Char): Boolean` and `booleanToChar(boolean: Boolean): Char` and noticed that the Room was just using the converter `booleanToChar(boolean: Boolean): Char` and not the other one. I believe this happened because after using the Converter, `Room` converted the `Character` datatype of Kotlin to a equivalent `String` while inserting. But while reading data it could not find any converter that would convert a `String` back to `Boolean`. So when I modified the converters to use `String` instead of `Char` the test passed successfully.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for reporting back, I'll add this piece of information to the answer for future readers to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this approach was that the boolean was converted to a `Char` correctly, but then stored as the SQLite type `TEXT`. When reading the datasets later, Room extracted the value as `String`, and the `charToBoolean` converter function would not be called. So after changing the converter function parameter type from `Char` to `String`, the conversion works:

```
@TypeConverter
fun stringToBoolean(value: String): Boolean {
    return when(value?: "F") {
        "T" -> true
        "t" -> true
        else -> false
    }
}
```

---

Note that Room is able to persist boolean values by default, so your `BooleanConverter` might be redundant. You could alternatively remove the Converter and change the query to

```
@Query(
    value = """
        SELECT * FROM alarm_resources
        WHERE
            is_scheduled = 1
        ORDER BY id ASC
    """
)
fun getAllScheduledAlarmResources(isScheduled: Boolean = true): Flow<List<AlarmResourceEntity>>
```

Internally, Room maps `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`. Note that this approach might break if Room decides to use another database than SQLite in the future (even though that's fairly unlikely).

To have a future-proof solution, use

```
@Query(
    value = """
        SELECT * FROM alarm_resources
        WHERE
            is_scheduled = :isScheduled
        ORDER BY id ASC
    """
)
fun getAllScheduledAlarmResources(isScheduled: Boolean = true): Flow<List<AlarmResourceEntity>>
```